# Accessing messages properties file in Grails using jQuery

Tags: jquery, grails, internationalization

I'm developing an application using `Grails 2.5.6`. I want to access the `message.properties` file but from `jQuery`. Is there any way or a plugin that may help me to achieve this.

Comment: take a look to this [grails plugin](https://grails.org/plugin/localizations?skipRedirect=true). In the download section it's enough to select your version

Answer (score 0):

From embedded JavaScript/jQuery code, in order to retrieve variables, objects as well as artefacts from the server side, for instance, `messages.properties`, we need to wrap jQuery codes inside `<g:javascript>...</g:javascript>`. From this point of view, you can access any message from messages.properties using a similar syntax:

```
<g:javascript>
...
...
set(messages, "onlyAcceptImages",
    "${g.message(code: "model.biomodels.curationNotes.editor.onlyAcceptImages")}");
...
...
</g:javascript>
```

In the above statement, `set` is the function whereby I assign a text get from messages.properties to the key `onlyAcceptImages` of the map `messages`.

To an individual javascript file with the extension js, I think we cannot do like this. Instead of going this way, you probably use grails plugin i18n asset pipeline. Read more here https://plugins.grails.org/plugin/amc-world/i18n-asset-pipeline

Comment: unfortunately i have to use this in external JS file

Comment: @SShehab: see my update for using external js files